# JavaScript alert() not working in embedded WebView

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, macos, webview

When embedding [`WebView`](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/DOCUMENTATION/Cocoa/Reference/WebKit/Classes/WebView_Class/Reference/Reference.html) in an application and loading html-pages in it, JavaScripts `alert()`/`confirm()`/etc. do not work.

Looking around in the documentation, there are no related settings in [`WebPreferences`](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/DOCUMENTATION/Cocoa/Reference/WebKit/Classes/WebPreferences_Class/Reference/Reference.html) - the only thing that looks related are `WebUIDelegate`s [`-(void)webView:runJavaScriptAlertPanelWithMessage:initiatedByFrame:`](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/DOCUMENTATION/Cocoa/Reference/WebKit/Protocols/WebUIDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#jumpTo_14) etc ... but implementing these would mean writing custom dialogs for these which seems pretty redundant...
I don't need a custom `WebUIDelegate` and would like to continue just using the default one.

Surely there has to be some way to simply enable `alert()` et al, but how?

Comment: The documentation for that delegate method says "No action is taken if you do not implement this method", so it seems like you've answered your own question.

Comment: I interpret that as *"No action is taken if you set a custom WebUIDelegate which does not implement this method"* - ideally i don't even want to set my own `WebUIDelegate`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It turns out there is simply no default `WebUIDelegate` set - Apple seems to expect everyone to implement the same basic features for themselves.

Comment: But js `prompt` works. So it's kind of inconsistent.

Answer (score 12):

Here is a sample code that will do the basic job. You need however to make sure that this object is registered as a UIDelegate for the WebView.

```
- (void)webView:(WebView *)sender runJavaScriptAlertPanelWithMessage:(NSString *)message initiatedByFrame:(WebFrame *)frame {
    NSAlert *alert = [[NSAlert alloc] init];
    [alert addButtonWithTitle:@"OK"];
    [alert setMessageText:message];
    [alert runModal];
    [alert release];
}
```

Comment: "You need however to make sure that this object is registered as a UIDelegate for the WebView."  That little blurb saved my evening.  Thanks.