# How to notify mouseEvents from Java Script to Cocoa?

Tags: javascript, objective-c, macos, cocoa, webview

```
[scriptObject evaluateWebScript:@"mouseClickCallBack =  function() { SampleWebViewApp. mouseClickCallBack(); } "];
```

I have a `WebView` and  I am able to capture the `mouseEvents` using `JavaScript`. Now I want to insert `textarea` at the mouse clicked position,for that I have to add the `textarea`, I would like to add it in the `Objective C`.How would I notify the `events` from `JavaScript` to `Objective C`.This is for `MAC OSX (cocoa)` not for `iPhone`. What `delegates` of the `webview` should I use to accomplish this?

Please suggest any alternative to accomplish the same ?

I have gone through this link.

[How to call Objective-C from Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1662473/how-to-call-objective-c-from-javascript)
But it is for `UIWebView`

I implemented the following API of `WebView`

```
+ (BOOL)isSelectorExcludedFromWebScript:(SEL)selector
{
    if ((selector == @selector(mouseClickCallBack)) 
    {
        return NO;
    }
    return YES;
}
```

But I am not sure where should I call the following code for mouseClick.

```
WebScriptObject *scriptObject;
   [scriptObject evaluateWebScript:@"mouseClickCallBack =  function() { SampleWebViewApp.mouseClickCallBack(); } "];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am able to solve this issue using alerts in `JavaScript` and these alerts are handled in WebView UIDelegate.

```
- (void)webView:(WebView *)sender runJavaScriptAlertPanelWithMessage:(NSString *)message initiatedByFrame:(WebFrame *)frame
```

Please refer the following link.

[JavaScript alert() not working in embedded WebView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2101611/javascript-alert-not-working-in-embedded-webview)