# OS X WebKit WebView don't show JS Popups

Tags: javascript, webview, xcode5

I just started to develop with xCode because i need a WebView container for a website.
It works so far but i can't logout on the website because there is (in a web browser) a popup window asking if i was sure to logout. I guess it is creates with javascript.

In the Web View settings there is a checkbox labeled "allow popups" but in my app no popup appears after the click.

I've searched for two hours and didn't find something similar related to my problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It was a confirm() function of javascript.

I got it to work with:

```
- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification
{
    [webView setUIDelegate:self]; // <------- This is an important part!!!
    [[webView preferences] setJavaScriptEnabled:YES];
    [[webView preferences] setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically:YES];
    [[webView mainFrame] loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:homeURLString]]];
}
```

and

```
- (BOOL)webView:(WebView *)sender runJavaScriptConfirmPanelWithMessage:(NSString *)message initiatedByFrame:(WebFrame *)frame {

    NSInteger result = NSRunInformationalAlertPanel(NSLocalizedString(@"JavaScript", @""),  // title
                                                    message,                // message
                                                    NSLocalizedString(@"OK", @""),      // default button
                                                    NSLocalizedString(@"Cancel", @""),    // alt button
                                                    nil);
    return NSAlertDefaultReturn == result;  
}
```

More Info [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/WebKit/Protocols/WebUIDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#jumpTo_15) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7268229/1005086).