# Javascript alert not showing in embedded WebView OSX

Tags: javascript, macos, cocoa, swift, webview

I have an embedded `WebView` `toWeb` that loads a local `HTML` file.

My alert `alert("Some message");` is not fired

The UIDelegate is set on `toWeb`

I have checked here:
[JavaScript alert() not working in embedded WebView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2101611/javascript-alert-not-working-in-embedded-webview)

and  [WKUIDelegate Protocol Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/WebKit/Reference/WKUIDelegate_Ref/index.html)

and came up with

```
func toWeb(sender: WebView!, runJavaScriptAlertPanelWithMessage message: String!) {

    let myPopup:NSAlert = NSAlert()
    myPopup.addButtonWithTitle("OK")
    myPopup.messageText = "An alert";
    myPopup.informativeText = "Message"
    if myPopup.runModal() == NSAlertFirstButtonReturn {

    }
```

However I still get no alert fired at all from my embedded `WebVieW`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorted it

```
 override func webView(sender: WebView!, runJavaScriptAlertPanelWithMessage 

    message: String!, initiatedByFrame frame: WebFrame!) {

            println("Alert sent")
            let myPopup:NSAlert = NSAlert()
            myPopup.addButtonWithTitle("OK")
            myPopup.messageText = "Title";
            myPopup.informativeText = "Message"
            if myPopup.runModal() == NSAlertFirstButtonReturn {

             }
```